# AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'listen''

Tags: python, speech-recognition

```
import speech_recognition

robot_ear = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
    print("Robot: I'm Listtening")

    audio = robot_ear.Listen(mic)

    audio = robot_ear.Listen(mic)
    print(you)
```

Comment: What's the `you` variable?

Comment: Try spelling `listen` with a lower-case `l`.